# Two views in one .xib; no addressabilty to 2nd UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have one (1) .xib with two UIViews, one on the top 1/3, the other on the bottom 2/3.  I can draw on the top view, but nothing on the bottom view.

I'm afraid that I don't have the bottom view connected properly.  The top view is connected to File's Owner, the bottom view to nothing.  When I try to connect the bottom view to File's Owner, the connection for the top view disappears.

How am I supposed to connect the views to the .xib so I can have addressability to both?

UPDATE:  This is an image of the structure of the app... as you can see, I have the xib and two controllers.  The xib has a class of "TDCalendarView"; the controllers apparently do nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create separate IBOutlets in the header file of the class that you are trying to connect the .xib to.

For example,

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet UIView *topView;
    IBOutlet UIView *bottomView;
}
@end
```

Then you can connect each view to a unique IBOutlet. You can only connect each IBOutlet to one view in your .xib file.

Comment: I got it working... I created a tab bar app and took one of the .xib files and added two UIViews.  Made each UIView a separate class, added an IBOutlet to each class and then connected them.  So far, so good.  Thank you.